# create a number of circular frames that matches the number of items in a list xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, frame

i don't know if my title suits my question but the idea is that i want to create circular frames according to the number of items in a list and if the number of frames created is more than what the screen can fit, i want the frames to continue on another row. i managed to create the frames but i don't know how to arrange them as i said. i thought about using a grid but the thing is, if i use a grid then i'll have to define a static number of columns in each row. but what if the user uses a tablet, then the screen size will be bigger and more frames could fit in the row. this is the code i wrote till now:

main.xaml.cs

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Frame circleImageFrame = new Frame
                {
                    Margin = 10,
                    BorderColor = Color.Black,
                    CornerRadius = 50,
                    HeightRequest = 60,
                    WidthRequest = 60,
                    IsClippedToBounds = true,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                    Content = new Image
                    {
                        Source = ImageSource.FromFile("user_profile.png"),
                        Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
                        Margin = -20,
                        HeightRequest = 100,
                        WidthRequest = 100
                    }
                };
                thislayout.Children.Add(circleImageFrame);
            }
}
```

main.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="stdprofiles.MainPage">

    <StackLayout x:Name="thislayout" Orientation="Horizontal">
        
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

in these pictures i am trying to illustrate my point. [image]

[image]

what layout should i use? thanks in advance

Comment: you can create a grid with a dynamic number of rows/cols

Comment: would you please give me an example because i tried searching "create a grid with dynamic number of rows and columns" but didn't find a suitable answer.

Comment: `grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { ... });`

Comment: thanks for your reply sir. Yes but how will i know that the screen doesn't fit anymore so i have to add a new row. and how will i know how many columns i should add. ```i<10``` is just an example. the list will be populated with data from a database so i actually don't know the number of items in it. so how should i determine that it's enough frames for this row now i have to move to a new one?

Comment: use math?  Divide the size of your screen by the size of the circle to see how many will fit in a row

Comment: I think FlexLayout fits good here. You can set how many items to fit the screen in percentages, put spacing between items, etc. Check this out: https://montemagno.com/flexlayout-image/